# Edited question, but reviewers refuse to reopen it. Why?

Tags: support, status-completed, editing, close-reasons

I posted the question and some members complained that is not understandable, one of the high reputation member edited question to fit the rules, he did a good job, but reviewers refuse to recognise that what he did was good edit. What should I do in this kind of [situation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62176/is-there-a-concept-of-qualification-examination-in-u-s-ph-d-programs-and-how-d?noredirect=1#comment148193_62176) ? Can this problem be resolved somehow?
what is typical process ?

Comment: Asking on Meta is the right next step. (However, I cannot really comment on your question, because I have little interested in U.S. PhD processes.)

Comment: I understand @Wrzlprmft can you comment on clarity of question and if it is understandable to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are experiencing the "typical" process. Unclear questions get put on hold and people edit them to make them better. Sometimes it happens in one go, sometimes it takes multiple edits. Sometimes you need to post in meta or chat asking how to salvage a question.

In this case, you attracted enough attention to your question and it is now reopen.

Comment: @stongBad do you remeber now?

Comment: @SSimon remember what? If this is related to some other conversation it would be better to comment there with a link to whatever content you want to remind me about. It is much easier to follow if everything is in one place.