# Two questions close without any notification? Why?

Tags: discussion

I dont understand, there was an attack on my profile while the whole controversy about the election when some of my questions are closed although edited and approved by the moderators jakebeal and others.
Negative downvoted was reversed but these closed questions are shocking to me, [Does this imply that I am ineligible to apply for this grant?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/104731/does-this-imply-that-i-am-ineligible-to-apply-for-this-grant)

Comment: The question you link to was closed March 2 - its closure doesn't seem to have anything to do with the election at all

Comment: If you think that you should be notified when your question is closed, I agree with you and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/255554) is the pertaining discussion on [meta.se]. If you want to dispute the closure of a specific question, please elaborate why you think it should not be closed, but please first read the close reasons and the links it contains. If you think that individual users are targetting you, please provide some evidence (and consider flagging for moderator attention as there is no point to take this out in the public).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft can you tell me the date when those questions are closed? and how I can see that?

Comment: @ff524 what about other one?

Comment: What other one? You only seem to have linked one question.

Comment: @SSimon: The dates are [in the close notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgTY2.png).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62176/is-there-a-concept-of-qualification-examination-in-u-s-ph-d-programs-and-how-d?noredirect=1#comment148193_62176

Comment: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/edited-question-but-reviewers-refuse-to-reopen-it-why @Wrzlprmft thank you

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I thought moderators can see all closed queestions, in which is easy to notice that most of them are close in time of election

Comment: @SSimon we can see things if we know where to look. It is helpful if you provide links to tell us where to look and a clear description of what we are looking for.

Comment: @StrongBad I am sorry, I didnt know that I assumed worngly, please take a look on the question linked in comment and qustion where I tag you. the one closed on 3rd march and 12th march. I appologize for inconvinience

Answer (score 6):

The SE system has a bot, a program running in the background, that attempts to handle "revenge" down voting and other inappropriate actions. The bot sometimes misses things and moderators, or even the SE team, need to step in and try and figure out what happened. In order to do that, we need a clear description of what we are looking for and why you think it is inappropriate.

Personal attacks are not allowed and claiming that your profile has been attacked is a big deal. Please provide us with the information we need so we can understand why you feel you were attacked and determine if it is in fact a target attack against you.

Comment: one is close as of topic, which is clearly not, I mean two moderators were involved in that question, one answered other one edited. non of them seemed to agree, other one was close after many years. I dont understand why since jakebeal did good job in editing